# "Background of" or "background for"

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing a paper about the interpretation of a treaty and I want to include a chapter on the historical background to explain why a certain article must be interpreted a certain way. In this context should I say *the historical background **for** Treaty X*, *the historical background **of** Treaty X* or use a different preposition entirely?

I checked both phrases on google and each had several million hits. *Background of* had more, but if the sense changes somewhat with the choice of preposition then that doesn't necessarily mean anything.

Comment: "I still find the prepositions thoroughly confusing." That means it's working!

Comment: "I still find the prepositions thoroughly confusing" implies **the** articles are still causing some confusion too.

Comment: Hey, never claimed prepositions were the only thing to throw me off ;)

Comment: You might want to consider using "historical context of" instead.  It may convey your meaning slightly more accurately.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of *Background For* typically I'd see *Historical Background of*, or *Treaty X's Historical Background*

Comment: This looks interesting since 'Treaty X's Historical Background == Historical Background of Treaty X'.

Answer (score 1):

People do often use *"of"* (or even *"for"*) as the preposition in this usage, but personally I prefer:

> "the historical background **to** [Treaty x]"

Comment: Could you briefly state your reasons? Intuitively, I likewise tend to prefer the proposition `to` over `of` -- being no native speaker, however, I am uncertain about my intuitions.

Comment: @ClintEastwood: It's not really a matter of "reasons/logic" - just idiomatic tendencies. I prefer the version I read/hear most often, which is probably the same one most other Anglophones use/encounter. In this context, our "intuitions" are nothing to do with telling us which preposition is objectively "correct" (at least three are "valid"). They just tell us which version we're most familiar with (which I still suspect is probably **to** for most native speakers, even if they haven't upvoted this answer).

Answer (score 0):

Neither are wrong. It's a matter of popularity of usuage and choice.

"Historical background of Treaty X" would be a more common usage.

Other common usages include:

> He comes from a background of illiteracy.